# Is there any way to make Java file selection dialogs remember the last directory?

Tags: java, swing, awt

When using Java applications, every time I open a dialog box, the starting directory is always my home directory.
Is there any way to make it remember the last used directory?

Alternately, are there *improved* Java file selection dialogs that allow type-to-search or any of the features that are standard in most other application file selection dialogs?

EDIT: I think the answers posted address the question for *writing* Java applications, but not for a user. Perhaps it's not possible for the user to change the file browser interface, but I'd like to know that. In case it matters, I have a few specific examples in mind (Amazon AWS uploader) but I have observed that behavior in most Java applications that use a file browser.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Store the file chooser as a class attribute.  When it is re-opened, the following will be preserved.

1. The directory.
2. The place in the directory to where the user had scrolled.
3. The selected file filter.
4. The size.
5. The location on screen.
6. The PLAF.
7. ..

---

> Is there any way to make it remember the last used directory?

Of course, if you mean persist the state *between runs,* there are a number of alternative forms of storing the details, and places/ways to store them.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777640/what-is-the-best-practice-for-setting-jframe-locations-in-java/7778332#7778332) for an example of storing the bounds of a `JFrame`  using a `Properties` file.

---

> Perhaps it's not possible for the user to change the file browser interface, ..

What 'user'?  Do you mean the developer who uses one in an app.?

Maybe what you need is to implement your own file chooser.  If that is the case, you might  start with the [FileBro](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/file-browser-gui) code.

[image]

Comment: +1 so simple. In other words, only create one and just reuse it over and over so it retains its state (selection, location, etc.)

Comment: By 'user', I meant end-user, not developer.  I am frequently forced to use java applications written by others that have file browser interfaces I don't like.  I suppose if I can get access to the source, I can change the file browser and repackage the code, so to that end your answer is pretty helpful.

Comment: Size and position are reset on every `showOpenDialog` for me (Java 17) when JFileChooser is kept as a field. The location is persisted indeed.

Answer (score 41):

JFileChooser does not remember it. However, Java provides a Preferences API

```
Preferences prefs = Preferences.userRoot().node(getClass().getName());
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser(prefs.get(LAST_USED_FOLDER,
    new File(".").getAbsolutePath()));
int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    // do something
    prefs.put(LAST_USED_FOLDER, chooser.getSelectedFile().getParent());
}
```

Comment: where is defined LAST_USED_FOLDER?

Comment: it's a constant.  Just define one.

Answer (score 9):

Swing `JFileChooser` has an method to set the initial directory. [setCurrentDirectory(File dir)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setCurrentDirectory%28java.io.File%29)
After the file has been chosen you can get the selected directory by calling [getCurrentDirectory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#getCurrentDirectory%28%29) and store it in some config file of your app.

Comment: That's a low-level function, right?  Is there any way to access and modify those variables as a user?

Comment: This is not as good a solution as retaining a reference to the chooser.  See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can cache the last dir location in application and while opening the file chooser specify the default location by [`setCurrentDirectory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setCurrentDirectory%28java.io.File%29)

Comment: I assume you are talking on Swing.

Comment: This is not as good a solution as retaining a reference to the chooser.  See my answer.

Comment: @Andrew its not about retaining the instance of filechooser its about just retaining a location

Comment: Think 'outside the box'.  Sometimes people don't know what is possible so don't quite know what they are asking for.

Comment: @Andrew _You can cache the last dir location in applicatio_ isn't this clearly telling that ??

Answer (score 0):

Here i used a simple code with directory dialog to open with last use directory

```
IDialogSettings dialogSettings = Activator.getDefault().getDialogSettings(); 
    String lastUsedPath = dialogSettings.get(IAntUIConstants.DIALOGSTORE_LASTANTHOME);
    if (lastUsedPath == null) {
        lastUsedPath = "c:\\";
    }
    DirectoryDialog dialog = new DirectoryDialog(Display.getDefault().getActiveShell());
    dialog.setFilterPath(lastUsedPath);
    String location = dialog.open();
    if (location == null) {
        return;
    }
    dialogSettings.put(IAntUIConstants.DIALOGSTORE_LASTANTHOME, location); 
      AntCorePreferences preferences = AntCorePlugin.getPlugin().getPreferences(); 
      String defaultHome = preferences.getAntHome(); 
      if (location.equalsIgnoreCase(defaultHome)) { 
          location = null; 
      }
```