# How I can add selected files history in JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

Please, can anyone help me to undersatand how I can save selected files history in JFileChooser and show it in the field where locates file name using comboBox.
Thanks.

Comment: `JFileChooser` provides the ability to supply an "accessory" view which you could use to list the recently opened files or provide a means for people to access that information. Start by having a look at [How to use file chooser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) for more details

Comment: @MadProgrammer, thanks, but I need to show it in the component where is last selected file, but there are must be more that one file. I don't need to create helping components.

Comment: Okay, so when the "okay" action is triggered on the `JFileChooser` maintain a reference to the last file/folder and if required, store in the system configuration.  The `Preferences` API would probably be the simplest solution

Comment: @MadProgrammer, yes. It helped. Thank you very much! It works as I want - thru whole system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swing JFileChooser has an method to set the initial directory when your button is pressed using method **setCurrentDirectory(File dir)**

You can always retrieve your last file accessed location using **getCurrentDirectory()**. You can then save it in some variable or in some configuration file and then retrieve it when the file chooser is enabled...

See also [Is there any way to make java file selection dialogs remember the last directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282048/is-there-any-way-to-make-java-file-selection-dialogs-remember-the-last-directory) for more information

Comment: Preferences helped. Thank you so much!