# JFrame set location at center of window on MAC OSX

Tags: java, macos, swing, jframe

Any body please can please help me, how to center a `JFrame` on Mac. OS X?

I have tried:

```
this.setLocationRelativeto(null);

this.setLocationRelativeto(this);
this.setLocationRelativeto(getRootPane());
```

..and

```
    final Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    final Dimension screenSize = toolkit.getScreenSize();
    final int x = (screenSize.width - this.getWidth()) / 2;
    final int y = (screenSize.height - this.getHeight()) / 2;
    this.setLocation(x, y);
```

None of the above worked, my frame is still at the bottom and hidden behind the Mac dock.

Comment: See also [How to best position Swing GUI's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7143398/418556) & [What is the best practice for setting JFrame locations in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7778332/418556).  Note that neither of those answers involves centering the GUI on screen.  There are better alternatives.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Location should be set after you packed your frame (wich calculates size of the frame).
And after that it should be made visible (it is hidden by default otherwize).

```
 pack();
 setLocationRelativeTo(null);
 setVisible(true);
```