# Save location in flow layout

Tags: java, swing, jframe, persistence, jtextpane

I have created a frame and two panels.

```
Jpanel pane11=new JPanel();
Jpanel pane12=new JPanel();
```

Added the `panel2` to the `panel1`

```
panel1.add(panel2);
getContentPane().add(panel1);
```

Now I set the `panel2` background white and it is working correctly

I have created 4 `JTextPanes` in the `panel2` and made it draggable.

**Now what my problem is:  If I drag a text pane from (0,0) to (10,10) and I save it the text pane has to reappear at (10,10) when I close and re open the frame.
So how to get the location of jtextpanes in flowlayout **

I have created save button to save the changes in panel and I am using flow layout for `panel2`.

I am using XML file for saving  the locations.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of what you have so far. 2) You've described a problem, but have so far not asked a question (let alone a specific, answerable question).  What *is* your question?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7778332/418556) for saving the properties of a `JFrame`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By design, `FlowLayout` will restore the panel to its calculated location when the enclosing `Window` is resized. As an alternative, consider [`JInternalFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html), which supports dragging in a `JDesktopPane` directly. Use the [*Preferences API*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/index.html) to persist each internal frame's location.

Comment: will the JInternal frame automatically resize the Jtextarea size.

Comment: I have seen in flow layout that it will automatically resize the textarea size .Will it be possible with JInternalFrame

Comment: Yes, depending on what layout you use in your `JInternalFrame`; `BorderLayout` is the default.

Answer (score 0):

try this,
save the finalx and finaly variables.

```
@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    if (panel.contains(e.getPoint())) {
        dX = e.getLocationOnScreen().x - panel.getX();
        dY = e.getLocationOnScreen().y - panel.getY();
        panel.setDraggable(true);
    }
}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    if (panel.isDraggable()) {
        finalx=e.getLocationOnScreen().x - dX;//save finalx and finaly
        finaly=e.getLocationOnScreen().y - dY;
        dX = e.getLocationOnScreen().x - panel.getX();
        dY = e.getLocationOnScreen().y - panel.getY();
    }
}
```

Comment: is draggable is not working it show no usage of isDraggable() to the jpanel

Answer (score -1):

You cannot save location while using flow layout.

If you would like to customize the whole layout, you could use

```
container.setLayout(null)
```

and give each component the location and size explicitly

```
setLocation(x,y)
setSize(w,h)
```

Comment: Don't suggest `null` layouts until ***all*** other possibilities have been explored.  In this case, other possibilities are.. the OP actually want to store the *index* of the items in the `FlowLayout`, the layout might best be set to a custom `DragAndDropLayout`, the items are better displayed in a `JList`..  There is a distinct lack of information needed to guide the OP to the best answer, so I feel *any* answer at this stage is largely speculative.