# Position a JFrame

Tags: jframe

I have a simple question. How do I set the position of a JFrame on the screen? When I use setVisible(), I want the window to appear in a certain location on the screen, perhaps by x-y coordinates. Is it possible?

EDIT: I found the solution. I had to call setLocationByOs(false) or something like that, then use setLocation(x,y)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
        final Dimension d = this.getToolkit().getScreenSize(); 
        this.setLocation((int) ((d.getWidth() - this.getWidth()) / 2), (int) ((d.getHeight() - this.getHeight()) / 2));
```

This lets the JFrame appear in the center of every screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for an existing answer before asking a new question. Entering your question into the StackOverflow search box would easily have given you an answer.

When you initialize your form just put `setLocation(int x, int y);` on the line after you call pack();

```
pack();
setLocation(int x, int y);
```

See here for a more in depth answer: [Best practice for setting JFrame locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777640/best-practice-for-setting-jframe-locations)

When looking for a method, you can often find it in the JavaDocs, for example the answer to your question: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setLocation%28int,%20int%29

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways you could approach this. Below is how I usually setup my JFrames:

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Window extends Canvas{
    public Window(Launcher launcher){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Example");
        frame.setSize(800,480);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(launcher);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        launcher.setFrame(frame);
    }
}
```

This class is initialized by `Launcher` which `extends Canvas implements Runnable` and uses threading.

`frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);` is the magic word.