# Handling exit button which is create automatically?

Tags: java, swing, listener, jbutton

I am building a text editor and I don't know how to handle a listener on Swing exit button, which is create automatically.
I want to use dialogs  when user doesn't save file, for example press exit button.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What does it mean created automatically ? By GUI builder ? So use the GUI builder to add a listener. If it has a listeners - edit it. If it doesn't and you can't add one - you can't use it.

Comment: Maybe he means the window decorations provided by Windows, Mac OS, or whatever operating system?

Comment: It is not clear what kind of exit-button you mean. You should add a screen-shot showing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a handle on your window, assuming it's a `Window` object (e.g. a `JFrame` or other kind of window), you can listen to `WindowEvent` events. Here is an example with `windowClosed`, you can replace it with `windowClosing` if you need to intercept it before.

```
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
            // do something here
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
final JFrame f = new JFrame("Good Location & Size");
// make sure the exit operation is correct.
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE); 
f.addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
        // pop the dialog here, and if the user agrees..
        System.exit(0);
    }
});
```

As seen in this [answer to Best practice for setting JFrame locations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7778332/418556), which serializes the frame location & size before exiting.

Answer (score 0):

Go stepwise:

1. Declare a boolean variable `saved` and set its default value to false.
2. When user saves the file, change it to true
3. When exit button is pressed, check the variable.
4. If `true`, exit, else, prompt user for saving file.

So, finally this code snippet looks like:

```
public boolean saved = false;

saveButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        saved = true;
        //Code to save file
    }
});

exitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(saved)
            System.exit(0);
        else {
            //Code to prompt user to save file
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: i cant add listener to exit button because this button is creating automatically

Comment: @thenewproblem add all important info to the question. Not in comments. What does it mean created automatically ? If it has a listeners - edit it. If it doesn't and you can't add one - you can't use it.